Python -i flag for production
I have a Python program that uses a watchdog, the watchdog is running on a separate thread. In the main thread, I have no code, so in order to keep the program running I'm using a while true sleep.
Should I use the -i flag instead to make the program stall?
Is it good for production?

If you only want one thread—the "watchdog" thread—to run, then why do you not let the main thread be that thread? What's the point of creating another thread? Why not simply have the main thread call the watchdog function?

@Ohm'sLawman library starts a different thread. It's a usage constraint.

Per the official documentation, a while-sleep loop is the idiomatic way of working with the library (as they don't offer running on the main thread).
They give the following usage example:
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, ".", recursive=True)
observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
finally:
    observer.stop()
    observer.join()

-i or interactive Python mode is not meant to be used as a blocking mechanism. Moreover, I fear that sending a sigint (Ctrl-C) will not actually exit the Python program in a clean fashion as the interactive interpreter catches those signals and eventually prints the KeyboardInterrupt exception without terminating.
If all the program does is hosting the watchdog, the while loop is probably a good solution. Otherwise, a signal handler can be registered, which triggers an event. The main thread can wait on this event or do other operations and eventually choose to terminate based on the event. I can add some example code if you wish. It will prevent the "useless" while loop.

Using while-true-sleep would probably be a more standard way to set up a production environment instead of adding flags for the interpreter.
You should also make sure that the watchdog thread is independent enough that it can't be crashed by the other threads. Depending on your set up, even multiprocessing might be suitable for this purpose instead of multithreading.

The point of my program is to make a “watchdog process”, so multiprocessing sounds a bit irrelevant, if I could I’d make the watchdog thread my main thread. I’m not sure it could be done since I have 5 handlers.

5 handlers? What does it mean? Is it just a different process watching over connections? Files? Making sure a process is alive? You should be able to make it the main thread. Are you using asyncio for the watchdog?

There are 5 polling observers that watch over different files. I’m not using asyncio, I’m using the simple “watchdog” library.
